# How to get a link to a gitlab comment (inside a merge reqeust) that I wrote?

Tags: gitlab

edit: Clarified that comments are in the context of a merge requests.

### screen shot: available icons on right of one of my merge request comments

This screenshot shows a fragment of a merge request comment (not publicly available) that I wrote, note lack of vertical "three dots" on right as shown in Sakura's screen short below.  My just shows a pencil for editing.

[image: available icons on right of comment]

I want to reference arbitrary discussion comments on some source code in merge requests.
edit: generalized my "my comments I created" to "general comments", added screenshot of an example from gitlab:

### screen shot: example comment from publicly accessible [**gitlab merge request #523**](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-development-kit/merge_requests/532)

Here is a publicly visible merge request at gitlab.com, I just chose this merge request at random because it had a fair number of comments. I chose this particular comment more or less randomly, and because the associated code fragment was short.

[image: screenshot: example from gitlab.com's merge request #523:]
If you search that merge request for this text you'll find a discussion matching the above comment.

```
 Toon Claes OOO
 @toon started a discussion on an old version of the diff 1 month ago
 Resolved by Toon Claes OOO 1 month ago
```

#### Original description:

Let me explain what I mean by link.

Gitlab sends me an email when *other* people make discussion comments, like
this example from a merge request discussion:

```
(i) | Samantha Q. commented on a discussion about a/b/c/foo.py:
    | 123       - # some ugly code
    |     123   + # some cleaner code
    | Some insightful comment here.
```

The **a/b/c/foo.py** in (i) above is a hyperlink like this:

```
<a href="http://e-gitlab.blarch.com/ai-group/hamster2/merge_requests/18#note_18536">a/b/c/foo.py</a>
```

Which is sort of ok for comments other people write, because I can copy the link from the email (assuming I still have it).  But I don't see a way to get this kind of link from discussion comments *anybody* wrote (originally emphasized comments that I wrote).

Can you tell me how to get a link like (i) from the gitlab user interface?

workaround: I can manually hack up a link by digging the note id **#note_18536** part out of *view source*, but that seems harder than it needs to be.
edit: also, this work around doesn't appear to work on possibly newer version of gitlab becuase when I go to search for the comment in view-source I can't find it, I don't know why - maybe it is dynamically populating the page via javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On gitlab, when you wrote a comment, you have a menu on the right of the comment header (see image):

[image: Gitlab comment header]

On these menu, you have two options:

- If you're the poster, you have the option for copy link, and delete comment.
- If you aren't the poster, you can report comment, or copy link.

I think that's resolves your question.

Comment: Thank you - I don't see the vertical dots you circled in my version, I edited my post to add a general screenshot showing comments in the context of a merge request.  Also added a screenshot showing a fragment of a merge request comment that I created.

Comment: I've follow your own link and I can see these dots. Maybe you have something configured on the theme?

Comment: Thank you, I see them at the gitlab link after registering and signing in.  Not seeing them in my inhouse gitlab, but there I'm on 9.1.0, while gitlab is showing enterprise edition 11.6.0.  That gives me something to pursue.